# \usepackage{karnaugh} causes emergency stop

Tags: packages, mac, latexian, karnaugh

I'm using Latexian under OS X, and whenever I try to import the package `karnaugh`, I get an emergency stop, caused by the package not being found. I went into TexLive's package utility, and found that `karnaugh` is, in fact, installed. After attempting to reinstall it, I get the same issue.

What's a possible fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `karnaugh.sty` file in the TeX distributions. You have to say

```
\input{kvmacros}
```

in order to load it.

Actually, the documentation says `\input kvmacros`, as this works also in Plain TeX, but the syntax with braces is preferred in LaTeX.